# Razer USB Headphones Linux Drivers

Tags: linux, headphones, elementaryos, usb-headset

How to use Razer Headphones USB on Linux? I tried razercfg but I don't know how to use it or if it helps.
And btw I've done my research. I know that Razer doesn't support Linux but if there is any 3rd party software I can use?

Comment: Please [don't do that](http://superuser.com/posts/1047833/revisions).

Comment: Ok i won't sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1396257#p1396257), they should just work but you won't get the extra features like 7.1 surround:

> Ok! So I went ahead and bought it - works fine. I added
>
> `load-module module-switch-on-connect`
>
> to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` as per
>   [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/P…SB_headset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pulseaudio#Automatically_switch_to_Bluetooth_or_USB_headset) so it gets
>   default automatically.